# Three.js How to get the bounding screen coordinate of a Sprite

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a scene with sprites in it.

[image]

As the first step, I tried to get it bounding box by using

```
var bbox = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(sprite1);
```

But it just returns a infinity box.

How do I get the screen coordinate (a and b) of the bounding box of sprite like this?
[image]

I am on r87

Edit:
I am not detecting a mouse movement or click. I am just going to put a HTML div right above the sprite. So I want to know its screen coordinate.

Comment: Are you trying to detect a hover/click based on screen coordinates? It may be easier to use a `Raycaster` to easily identify which sprite you're selecting. That way you won't have to continuously update your screen bounding coordinates.

Comment: If it's some irregular shape based on a mesh, you need to project all the points, and find the min/max in screen space. If you know it's a sphere/disc, you can project just the center, and find the radius in screen XY.

Comment: @TheJim01 No, I am not trying to detect a mouse event. I want to get the screen coordinate of an arbitrary Sprite object.

Comment: @pailhead Oh, so it seems there is no easy method to even know the rough rectangle bounds of a sprite? I will try the "project all points" method first. Thanks